# simplify JS conditions into if else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to simplify this conditions into just if((A && B && C) || (!A && !B && !C)){..} else {..}.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: are `A`, `B`, and `C` booleans? Or truthy/falsy values?

Comment: Yeah, those are booleans

Comment: Can you add more information about what you want the solution to look like?

Comment: what is `active` and `inactive`?

Comment: It is ember JS. Can it be simplified to just if((A && B && C) || (!A && !B && !C)){..} else {..}?

Comment: You got `A && B` twice. Could you show us your real code please?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
const vals = [];
if (A) vals.push('A');
if (B) vals.push('B');
if (C) vals.push('C');
if (vals.length > 0 && vals.length < 3)
  this.set(`controller.options.state`, vals.join(','));
else
  delete options.state;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const conds = {A,B,C};
const keys = Objects.keys(conds);
if(keys.every(k => conds[k]) || keys.every(k => !conds[k])){
  delete options.state;
} else {
  this.set(`controller.options.state`, keys.filter(k => conds[k]).join(','));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```js
switch (4 * A + 2 * B + C) {
case 0:
    console.log("None");
    break;
case 1:
    console.log("C");
    break;
case 2:
    console.log("B");
    break;
case 3:
    console.log("B,C");
    break;
case 4:
    console.log("A");
    break;
case 5:
    console.log("A,C");
    break;
case 6:
    console.log("A,B");
    break;
case 7:
    console.log("A,B,C");
    break;
}
```

See the demo.

```js
for (const A of [false, true]) {
    for (const B of [false, true]) {
        for (const C of [false, true]) {
            console.log(test(A, B, C));
        }
    }
}

function test(A, B, C) {
    switch (4 * A + 2 * B + C) {
    case 0:
        return "None";
    case 1:
        return "C";
    case 2:
        return "B";
    case 3:
        return "B,C";
    case 4:
        return "A";
    case 5:
        return "A,C";
    case 6:
        return "A,B";
    case 7:
        return "A,B,C";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps more straight forward as `0b100 * A + 0b010 * B + 0b001 * C` :P

Answer (score 1):

You could change the first condition to check if all variables have the same value, then delete, otherwise take and array with corresponding letters.

```js
function check(a, b, c) {
    if (a === b && b === c) {
        console.log(a, b, c, 'delete options.state');
    } else {
        console.log(a, b, c, `this.set('controller.options.state', '${['A', 'B', 'C'].filter((_, i) => [a, b, c][i]).join()}');`);
    }
}

check(false, false, false);
check(false, false, true);
check(false, true, false);
check(false, true, true);
check(true, false, false);
check(true, false, true);
check(true, true, false);
check(true, true, true);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(A && B && C) || (!A && !B && !C)
```

is equivalent to

```
A === B && B === C
```

since either `A`, `B` and `C` are all `true` or they are all `false`. In either case, they are equal. If `A` equals `B` and `B` equals `C` then transitively `A` also equals `C`. Alternatively this can be expressed as `A === B && A === C` - using the same logic but transitively `C` is equal to `B`.

However, if you wish to simplify the whole `if`/`else` chain, you can easily encode it in a table and do a lookup instead of `if`/`else`es. This can help if there are different things that can happen in different conditions as you can more easily encode and find what is where:

```
//create the initial table
const table = {
  true : { true: {}, false: {}, },
  false: { true: {}, false: {}, },
}

const shared = ({options}) => delete options.state;
//fill in the table with handlers
//    |  A  ||  B  ||  C  |
table [true ][true ][true ] = shared;
table [false][false][false] = shared;
table [true ][true ][false] = ({self}) => self.set(`controller.options.state`, 'A,B');
table [false][true ][true ] = ({self}) => self.set(`controller.options.state`, 'A,C');
table [true ][false][false] = ({self}) => self.set(`controller.options.state`, 'A');
table [false][true ][false] = ({self}) => self.set(`controller.options.state`, 'B');
table [false][false][true ] = ({self}) => self.set(`controller.options.state`, 'C');

/* ... */
//get handler or use a default no-op
const handler = table[A][B][C] ?? () => {};
handler({options, self: this});
```

In this case, all handlers take an object with a `self` and a `options` property, so they can use it as needed.